# Can not reproduce behavior within testcase: Duplicate accounts after merge

Tags: trigger, unit-test, failing-tests

I'm sorry for the vague description in the header. So here's my problem in detail:
I have an automation, that essentially checks a "potential" child record (not master-detail, just lookup) of accounts, and if some specific criteria are met, a new account is beeing created.

However, when I merge two accounts that both have a child record

1. the "losing" acocunt gets deleted (intended)
2. immediately a new account is re-created (not intended)
3. the child-record of the old account is related to the created third account (not intended)

Now my thing is: When I try to reproduce this behavior within a unit test, it doesn't work. Here's my test code:

```
// SETUP the accounts and ProdOrganisations and other records 
// that are needed to meet the criteria

// ACTION
Test.startTest();
Database.MergeResult mr = Database.merge(accs[0], accs[1], false); // accs is a list of two records, I previously set up
Test.stopTest();

// EXPECTED
// merge successfull
System.assertEquals(true, mr.isSuccess());
// only one account left
System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account]);
// both orgas related to master account
for (ProdOrganisation__c po : [SELECT Id, id__c, Account__c FROM ProdOrganisation__c]) {
    System.assertEquals(mr.getId(), po.Account__c, 'PO '+po.id__c+' related to wrong account');
}
```

the first two tests pass, e.g. MergeResuls is success, only one account is existing, the second account is deleted (checked with `ALL ROWS`).
However, I do not understand at all, why the third assertion fails: when it iterates the second po record, it says that this po is still related to the second account (the deleted one). When testing this via the UI, this is definitely not the case: The **second** account is properly deleted and a **third** account is created.

Could anybody explain this behavior to me please? Especially how to reproduce the real-world behavior in tests?

Comment: Can you add the trigger code you are testing against?

Comment: I guess it is way to complex, to put into one small post. My primary concern is why does it delete the account in the test and not via the UI; why does it keep the PO related to the deleted account (from merge statement) in the test but not via the UI?

I'm not entirely certain, that my issue is actually related to my implementation or if its more of a general issue with my understanding of execution context, Database.Merge, cached variables, etc. Cut a long story short: Clearly, there is something I dont understand. Unfortunately, I don't even know what questions to ask.

Comment: In your test class, are you running the same steps as your test in the UI in the same order? I just want to make sure everything is running the the same order.  Also does your trigger update the PO in any way?

Comment: You mentioned that account (third) is created only if some specific criteria met, so looks like these criterias are met when you test using UI but not when you write unit tests.